# Subclassing org.apache.log4j.Logger without altering %C?

Tags: java, log4j

To enable things like

```
logger.info("This is a formatted number: %.2f", number)
```

I decided to write a subclass of `org.apache.log4j.Logger`. I know, I could have written a wrapper class to achieve the same result but since I'm adding a lot of appenders to the logger at runtime I prefer to use inheritance.

The subclass looks like this:

```
public final class FormatLogger extends Logger {

private final static FormatLoggerFactory factory = new FormatLoggerFactory();

protected FormatLogger(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
    return Logger.getLogger(name, factory);
}

public void fatal(String formatter, Object... args)  {
    log(Level.FATAL, formatter, args);
}

public void log(Level level, String formatter, Object... args) {
    if (super.isEnabledFor(level)) {
        super.log(level, String.format(formatter, args));
    }
}
}
```

Everything works nicely - everything but one thing: the message text now adds the name of the logger subclass instead of the name of the class calling the logger.
As pattern layout, I use the following format:

```
[%d{yyyyMMdd HHmmss}] %-5p [%t] %C: %m%n
```

i.e. things look like this:

```
[20110525 214515] INFO  [main] org.xyz.FormatLogger: This is a formatted number: 23.23
```

instead of:

```
[20110525 214515] INFO  [main] org.xyz.Main: This is a formatted number: 23.23
```

Is there some way to do such thing "properly" so that "%C" keeps printing the original class name?

Comment: You could just use log5j, which is a wrapper around log4j that provides a vararg-style logger interface. No reason to reinvent the wheel.  http://code.google.com/p/log5j/

Comment: A minor addition to a polished product isn't reinventing the wheel, IHMO. For me, switching to another library and migrate all existing log4j calls is much more of a hassle than adding a few lines of code. Of course, if one starts a new project, it will make sense to use log5j or logcenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: add a fully qualified class name (FQCN), i.e.:

```
static String FQCN = FormatLogger.class.getName() + ".";
```

The log(..) method must then be modified like this:

```
super.log(FQCN, level, String.format(formatter, args), null);
```

This is perfectly shown in the example MyLogger.java that comes with log4j. -1 for my own laziness!

Comment: Don't worry, I think I missed this too.  I did effectively the same thing, but it was much more complicated.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Minor addition: I was able to get this working with log4j version 1.2.15 but not version 1.2.16 (gives me a "?" at the %C position).

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but I ended up creating a wrapper and passing in the class name to it.  Then with this class name I prepended it to the front of all the 4 logging levels which I was already wrapping anyway.  It's quite messy, but I couldn't find another way of doing so.  My logging statements now spit out the logger name then the package/class name.  Its a bit cumbersome, but I'd rather have the extra information vs having not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "." on the end of the FQCN String, to correctly log with Log4J 1.2.16 version or later.